# Winforms Application with SQL DB not working on any machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I created a windows forms application. I use SQL server DB for the data.
It is working fine on my machine, but when I try and make this application work on any other machine, it is not working.

I installed SQL Server Express 2012 on another machine and tried and opened the application, but without any luck.

The connection string that I have in the app.config file is:

```
add name="dbSearch_v1.Properties.Settings.dbuserConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db\db2016.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Is there anything that I should do to make this work on any machine I Put the application on?

Thanks!

Comment: The connection string that i am using is:

Comment: Is it just not working? Any errors/exceptions/logs?

Comment: Is the server hosted locally on each machine or do they need to connect to a hosted server?

Answer (score 1):

the SQL Server is installed in the other machines? with the same database, stored procedures and tables?

or maybe, if all the others computers needs to call the database on your machine, you must change the connection string:

connectionString="Data Source=(your IP or Pc Name)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db\db2016.mdf;Integrated

Comment: No, the sql server is not installed on the other machines, I just installed the sql express on them so that the application won't crash and the .mdf file is placed within the application debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the SQL Configuration Manager and enable the sockets for SQL Express. By default 'localhost' is on, but you need to enable the LAN Address to listen on that port as well. Also make sure your firewall is off.

[image]

Mine is the full version of SQL, so it will look a little different, but this should kind of explain where I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This may not even be an option but a settings windows like this can do wonders in terms of connectivity. Also make sure that the SQL Server Agent / Browser are started in the services.msc.

[image: Server Settings]

Also depending on the setup, embedding sql server with your application can save time as well. You can install it in quiet mode too.

Answer (score 0):

You must install SqlLocalDB.MSI on machine that you want to run the application. For SQL Server 2012 go to this link [SqlLocalDB.MSI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29062) and download SqlLocalDB.MSI